# User Contributed Rating System

Tags: system

I am working on developing a user contributed rating website, much like rottentomatoes.com in a lot of aspects. Are there any open source content management systems that I can use as the foundation of what I am building?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try Wordpress with some plugins like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/. Then, for every movie/book/game/whatever, you can make a new post, and people will be able to review it. You can just leave the homepage and it will display that newest additions, or you can make it display a static page too.

Comment: thank you so much, but i was looking for something more customizable -i'm a python wen developer (i primarily work with django or pyramid) and was hoping for something maybe on that kind of platform. how customizable and how easy is it so customize wordpress?